# NuGet packages from TeamCity are not visible in DNX project

Tags: nuget, teamcity, dnx

I have Nuget Server on TeamCity and when i try download package from server to dnx project list of the packages is empty, but when i try manualy add to project (by project.json) then it works.

How i should configure my TeamCity Nuget server or something other?

Comment: [Did you add the feed to visual studio?](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: No i not found solution, but if you add NuGet package in project.json then VS find it and add to project.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an issue with TeamCity's NuGet server as NuGet's public servers behave just fine. If I were to guess, there is some problem with passing in arguments for .NET Core assemblies / framework projects.

You want to have the [TeamCity .NET Core plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-dotnet-plugin) installed on TeamCity and use the "dotnet restore" command -- with the TeamCity URL for your NuGet package - and it should work as expected after that. For solutions mixed with csproj and xproj files, it has been my experience that you need a NuGet Installer and dotnet restore build step to get the job done. For NuGet, you want to have 3.5.0 (only available in beta at the time of this writing) or later to understand projects that contain a project.json -- and to not error out.